Unable to Dockerize Spring Boot Application: Failing to Connect to PostgreSQL Docker Container
I am unable to Dockerize my Spring Boot application. Without Docker, the project is running well on localhost, but I read somewhere that I should use my Postgres docker service name (which is postgresdb) in datasource url. But it is neither working with postgresdb nor with localhost. I am new to Docker, so may be I am missing something very trivial. This is my application.properties file:
spring.application.name=pit

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/donations
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jackson.time-zone=IST
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.security.user.name=harshit
spring.security.user.password=123
    
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM amazoncorretto:17

WORKDIR /back-end
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install

CMD mvn spring-boot:run

This is docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRESDB_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRESDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRESDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $POSTGRESDB_LOCAL_PORT:$POSTGRESDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgres
    networks:
      - sng-network

  app:
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    build: ./
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:$POSTGRESDB_DOCKER_PORT/$POSTGRESDB_DATABASE",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "$POSTGRESDB_USER",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "$POSTGRESDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - sng-network

volumes:
  db:

networks:
  sng-network:
    driver: bridge

This is the error stack-trace:
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [The connection attempt failed.] [n/a]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
        ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:358) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        ... 117 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgresdb
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:572) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
        ... 131 common frames omitted

Please help me figure out the issue.

How are you running this compose file? "I should use my Postgres docker image name " is untrue, it should be the service name, not image name, but I assume that's just a misunderstanding since the service name is postgresdb and you are using it correctly it seems.

@TeemuRisikko I am running using docker-compose up. Also tried docker-compose up --build

Remove the port in the datasource url value

@akuma8 It didn't work. I also tried using 0.0.0.0 in port, and it also didn't work.
